# Is there are cleaner way to Structure your TestNG test cases?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testing, testng

My question is more to do with structure/cleanliness. I have a test script in TestNG and am looking to add test cases to expand. I want to know if there is a clean way to repeat test cases. Example :

I can do :

```
@Test(priority=0, name = login )
//some code

@Test(priority=2, name = submit )
//some code

@Test(priority=3, name = accept )
```

That is just one test scenario. Now I want to do the same thing for a different flow but the test case is repeating ... example:

```
@Test(priority=0, name = login )
//some code

@Test(priority=2, name = submit )
//some code

@Test(priority=3, name = rejected )
```

In both flows, 2 tests are the same where I am repeating login and submit. The only change in flow would be what happens each time after submission, such as Submit, Rejected, Cancelled etc. etc. I only know of one way, and that is to repeat writing the login and submit each time.

**The question is, is there better/cleaner more structured way to write this instead of the below where I keep repeating login every time?**

```
@Test(priority=0, name = login )
//some code

@Test(priority=2, name = submit )
//some code

@Test(priority=3, name = accept )
//Some code

@Test(priority=4, name = login )
//some code

@Test(priority=5, name = submit )
//some code

@Test(priority=6, name = rejected )
//some code
.
.
.
@Test(priority=n ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to remove duplication of tests, how about creating more invidualized tests and running them multiple times by specifying so in a [testng.xml file](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml)?

For example, you could do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<suite name="Test Suite 1">
    <test name="Test Set 1">
        <classes>
            <class name="test.mytest.Test1" />
            <class name="test.mytest.Test2" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test Set 2">
        <classes>
            <class name="test.mytest.Test1" />
            <class name="test.mytest.Test3" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

With your classes set up as:

```
public class Test1 {

    @BeforeMethod
    public void before(){
        System.out.println("==Before method==");
    }

    @Test
    public void testLogin(){
        System.out.println("test login");
    }

    @Test
    public void testSubmit(){
        System.out.println("test submit");
    }

}

public class Test2 {

    @Test
    public void testAccept(){
        System.out.println("test accept");
    }

}

public class Test3 {

    @Test
    public void testReject(){
        System.out.println("test reject");
    }

}
```

When run(I used Maven in my example), will produce:

```
Running TestSuite
==Before method==
test login
==Before method==
test submit
test accept
==Before method==
test login
==Before method==
test submit
test reject
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.253 sec - in TestSuite
```

For this example I organized them by class, but you could organize by group, method, etc.

**EDIT**
Based on your comment I added an example of using @BeforeMethod and the output produced.

If you are looking to specifically reuse your @BeforeMethod, I suppose you could always just throw it into a base class and have your test cases extend it:

```
public class TestBase {

    @BeforeMethod
    public void before(){
        System.out.println("==Before method==");
    }
}

public class Test1 extends TestBase{

    @Test
    public void testLogin(){
        System.out.println("test login");
    }

    @Test
    public void testSubmit(){
        System.out.println("test submit");
    }

}
```

I've never needed to do something like that, so I can't speak to it in terms of best practices, but it would work.

Comment: This looks like it'll solve what I need it to do. Although, a follow up question is , where would the beforeMethod be ?

Comment: I'm not certain what you are using it for, so it's hard to say where it should go for your specific case. I modified my answer to show a sample of using @BeforeMethod and the output it would produce.

Comment: perfect. that is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Glad to hear it. If that is the case would you mind marking the question as answered?

Answer (score 0):

Will this work ?

```
public class BeforeStuff {
@BeforeMethod()
}

public class Test1 {
    @Test
    @Test
}

public class Test2 {
    @Test
}

public class Test3 {
    @Test
    }
}
```